# Add mainTableView to represent self.tableView instead of searchResultsTableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I hide the searchViewController.searchResultsTableView to display the results in the main UITableView instead. But the self.tableView = searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView so the mainTableView is unscrollable when typing search text or after "Search" is hit. How can I make the self.tableView represent the mainTableView?

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden=YES;
return YES;
}
```

Comment: are you able to get the search result into the mainTableView so that you can see it and so the only issue is that you can't scroll it?